# Expectation value of Commutator of Hermitian operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

Assume $\hat{A},\hat{B},\hat{C}$ are Hermitian.

$$[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=i\hat{C}$$ and $$\hat{A}|a\rangle=a|a\rangle.$$ Then 
$$\langle a|i\hat{C}|a\rangle=\langle a|[\hat{A},\hat{B}]|a\rangle =0 .$$

Is this result significant if $\hat{A},\hat{B}, \hat{C}$ are observables in quantum mechanics like $\hat{L_x},\hat{L_y}, \hat{L_z}$? Is it a bit odd if $\hat{A}=\hat{x},\hat{B}=\hat{p}, \hat{C}=\hbar I$, the unit operator?

Comment: Write out the commutator in full to see why the ev has to be zero.

Comment: What do you mean with "What does it mean?". The identity holds for arbitrary operators of that kind. Unless you givre $A,B,C$ physical meaning, there's no question here.

Comment: Let $\hat{A}=\hat{L}_x,\hat{B}=\hat{L}_y$ then $\hat{C}=\hbar \hat{L}_z$. The expectation value of $\hat{L}_z$ in the eigenstates of $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$ must be zero. It appears odd.

Comment: There are two possibilities: Either, there is nothing odd at all, or you are thinking that $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ must have nonzero eigenvalues. This however is wrong - you can show that neither of the two operators can be bounded and neither needs to have any eigenvalue at all. I believe this was asked before, but can't find where...

Comment: @Martin perhaps you were there in chat when I discussed a very similar exercise (the first one Siedentop gave in the Mathematical Quantum Mechanics course, haha)

Comment: @Danu: No, I wasn't - but of course we had the same exercise - and I think it's a beautiful one!

Comment: @Martin I guess some things don't change ;)

Comment: It is not a good practice to change the entire question after posting it once. You should ask a separate question if you have another question.

Comment: @user40330 It *is* good practice to edit questions that have been placed on hold, in order to make them better. That said, I still don't see what is actually being asked here.

Answer (score 2):

$\langle a|i\hat{C}|a\rangle=\langle a|[\hat{A},\hat{B}]|a\rangle = \langle a| \hat{A}\hat{B}-\hat{B}\hat{A}|a \rangle = \langle a|\hat{A}\hat{B}|a\rangle - \langle a|\hat{B}\hat{A}|a \rangle = a^{*}\langle a|\hat{B}|a \rangle - a \langle a|\hat{B}|a\rangle = 0 $

(Since $a^{*}=a$ because $\hat{A}$ is Hermitian and Eigen Values of Hermitian operators are real)

EDIT: The question was changed after I added the answer.